# is two's complement addition of two positive numbers the same as normal addition?

Tags: math

if i have two positive integers, say 0x1234 and 0x5678, is 0x8765 + 0xfedc = 0x8641, if the '+' means two's complement addition, mod 2^16?

Comment: what? Doesn't make any sense that I can detect. I don't what what the first two numbers are about, the last sum is true mod 2^20, and two's complement has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as "two's complement addition of positive numbers" because two's complement is a way of storing negative numbers: -n is stored as ~n + 1, which is equivalent to 2^w - n where w is the width of the integer type.

Two's complement is designed for modulo 2^w arithmetic: (+a) + (-b) is represented as a + (2^w - b) = (a - b) + 2^w, which gives the correct answer of a-b after reduction modulo 2^w.  Similarly, (-a) + (-b) is represented as (2^w - a) + (2^w - b) = (-a - b) + 2 * 2^w, which reduces to the expected -a - b.

Comment: okay, but there is no reason to see any of the values as negative in the RC5 algorithm, so what was do the instructions mean?

Answer (score 1):

This question is exceedingly vague.  That said:

On the bit level, twos complement addition is equivalent to modular addition of unsigned integers.  The only difference is in how you interpret the bit patterns of the inputs and result.

This means that if you have two positive 16-bit twos complement numbers, a and b, then twos_complement_add(a,b) is:

- a + b if (a+b) < 2^15
- a + b - 2^16 otherwise